# Long-lived state across many MVC web sessions

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, session-state

I need to build an MVC site where the data model is seemingly not right for a database and certainly can't be rebuilt every session. Is there a way to effectively create a static class in an MVC site that is used by all users/ sessions of a web site... over weeks at a time?

Detail: 
I have a C# class that extracts state from a controller offering an raw socket feed (think RS232). The data rate of this controller is slow and to build proper classes, required extracting state, string names for each item, etc. This takes 30 seconds to do. There are 2 dozen or so objects in the device class so it’s not a trivial one. This is why I suggested serialization to SQL would not be a good fit.

Using desktop application terminology… When an app is loaded is initializes its static classes. The constructor of the static class would run once and get the current state. It would also register a aw socket handler to continuously maintain active state of the class model.  Then, as users request web pages, the site can use this shared data model.

Simpler is better here as I’m not a full time developer. e.g.: I’d rather not build a complete web service and then have to marshal all the data across JSON for the 2 dozen or so objects in the device classes.

Comment: Can you show us any code?

Comment: Might be possible with App fabric caching

Comment: Thanks asawyer. I really like Azure and AppFabric but it's not suitable to this on-premises offer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a very bad idea, but you could use the HttpApplication-object which is shared by all users and lives as long as the application lives.

Apart from that there's nothing you can do to keep it longer then the application. When the application dies (for example 20 minutes of inactivity, or the site is restarted, ... ) all memory is released, so there's no place you can store it other then a persistent mechanism (such as a DB).

If you find that mapping that model to a relational DB is too much effort you might want to look into a NoSQL solution such as MongoDB, Riak, ... What you do is basically serialize it to JSON and save the whole graph. You can then retrieve it afterwards by just deserializing it.

Comment: Thanks Kenneth. This is very helpful. I'm reading up on MongoDB now. It would seem like using a C# CLI appp that interfaces with the controller and maintains an up to date MongoDB would let me use a more normal (stateless) web pattern for the view layers.